# Did Konstantin Korotkov take a photograph of the life force leaving a dead body?

Tags: mortality, spirituality

ADG (UK) - Alien Disclosure Group - published a story in September 2013:

> The timing of astral disembodiment in which the spirit leaves the body has been captured by Russian scientist Konstantin Korotkov, who photographed a person at the moment of his death with a bioelectrographic camera.
>
> [image]
>
> The image taken using the gas discharge visualization method, an advanced technique of Kirlian photography shows in blue the life force of the person leaving the body gradually.

Is this for real?

Comment: looks like a multi-exposure where the dude is laying down or sitting up during the exposures

Comment: Where is the link to that story? What is a *bioelectrographic camera* and the *gas discharge visualization method*?

Answer (score 7):

There are actually two claims here:

- Did Konstantin Korotkov take such a photograph?
- Is this the photograph?

I propose to let someone else address the debunking of [Kirlian photography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirlian_photography) as a method of capturing images of souls.

I will address the second part:

**This image was NOT taken by Korotkov.** This is a stock image that has been (accidentally?) [attached to the story](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZiuyPtxHYZDvF4st1awCKsWaFTWToUeMER_1jqBtVHrWaNE74cV1eDZrXwBRIsXPYzpfz3zWhZm_1nlghK0lZCHBSJTRma_1zuQRQDaVyEUp6dtOwqhjauPglahhK96aqaBLFs8MuGntmLHB4dnZGeF929xuhAfS9PzZtpVjKkpIILtoiRQQ-IHrdqZO7ZDrz6n25MOd3BvaKInEVnRFCPU-QjCHVa8jEQwOWQ1iMp7XjyHEjXW4QB0ySPSBynpaDTc94-lMI738STHRU5j9fCNwX_118dRmXnNTHCLe0R0rPUUqrLAv-eNMF8wns32pkPgGP30_12WADe0GGeO7fyGTHVWoP9b4KRkGtrGzY9YM4e2glpSiheGYm1V6KJYlniY_1bXrH3DW_1ocXIFoYn2-HdIGt0jlKf-fIAloZW8Rdf1aqlCFyxJc619UZod3P52fa68yti9XZIaqxLdVWSoVluLjJNQtSDSEzPwHubo_1VpkSsZU_1pMUlF7UN3ryfx5atS_15Zvo9CnVWa5jnXfUk7I4QzGbp89s6Mq5qcBHnNAe49py4OFjJDCwAh67Jf2w9E53wP3qMdoGvpEXrRZJN-k5GeyF1IeUPnim_11JGAF1m437FrwUqCQxaJHRXuTYy-R-oFsY1glE9SfO2Z4kADMPgAaPxYl3rQQo8Fcz44AYoWtIRS4-X8dFhTSQNdjY-1L0rNfKwRo7eym9ThuRMS-DUhe3LlHn3w_1-etlcSxsxXd3wMLoGbC8tlVEVEMmOOmb3iL1liE0PEXRSpv1KpiITOQ6nkQO4aFCPz8HOdGYv6f1UZ82a8-OdosDFS0LzsR2wEd6ybdwZSXeOzuu9mJxtUzNGevxeq1u1Ro6CbILzqoVTTLkoy-FZalCaOspGyvXusfbhdLCW7R7b7sbRLyOtp6TwqANHbYy8HSkDDHjY0g2Ob9jdQOvSk2yO5A6Ou8jffmj92AThKs0iJkoTzMgpDCxV8zS8YYYYxD5qkRxMDiDgnV4TrAiRCa0MRRF57gcd7TTwPw7Ck_1VS6fyQHv5ftBR6z5LlGoGPU_18oNAUdhQueIVfGPmnK9E2QhoF4UzjHpWiDSi73y-M8Fl8lK6Xj2yV2REpSai5ypcHn7cWLyKHp3uW6ZaoJHDydPVH4xWQ0oDfHhERnYbYIAqGH1iS4DfwmrXpIQVAp5VfmTdjzUBwbmoOKY4GHT4D0og0Y4Jty9sRpl3SAdB8tEts7stJ3I-vk6CC0JraIoxWk8TKk2DuUfq-cKRE6tRfHPKEa8KiI6BPoOsogQZ9nGIV8W8eQsmZOh2ieBBsylLwMkGdGfvmcsPnFwN5ZTt1W3Mvk2nwSnaZ9eJsQx_1HcQClWsEBg1FCemDh73rB4qR-vEVdc8mlFcTyOYnsy8&biw=1536&bih=860&site=imghp&sa=X&ei=aFhFUr2DK8mAlQWTx4CIBg&ved=0CE8Q9Q8oAA).

The original was produced by [Oscar Buriel](http://www.sciencephoto.com/media/287461/enlarge) as part of a larger series.

[image]

Hat tip to [Mick West from MetaBunk](http://www.metabunk.org/threads/debunked-soul-leaving-body-photo-russian-scientist-konstantin-korotkov.2447/) for finding this.

The same site shows *another* false image that has attached to this story, this time thermal images showing the effect of a sauna on the body.

Comment: And to explain how that photo was taken, here's a video that shows just how to do it in your own bedroom with a DSLR and tripod: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dzJzpMz4qBY

Comment: The fact that the caption refers to something being "shown in blue" when there's very obviously nothing blue in the photograph is also something of a give-away.